# How to effectively use ffplay with -bsf?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, kubuntu

I am using Kubuntu 22.04.

Output of `ffmpeg -hide_banner -buildconf`:

```
  configuration:
    --extra-libs=-lpthread
    --enable-gpl
    --enable-gnutls
    --enable-libass
    --enable-libfreetype
    --enable-libmp3lame
    --enable-libopus
    --enable-libdav1d
    --enable-libvpx
    --enable-libx264
    --enable-libx265
    --enable-libpulse
    --extra-cflags=-O3
    --disable-debug
```

Here's my attempt to effectively use `-bsf` on ffplay:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -bsf:v name=param -c copy -f webm - | ffplay -
```

But on seeking, it breaks like this:

```
[matroska,webm @ 0x7faf20000c80] Unknown element A3 at pos. 0x15009 with length 0x165 considered as invalid data. Last known good position 0x1e5, 20 unknown elements in a row
[matroska,webm @ 0x7faf20000c80] Unknown element 82 at pos. 0x1500c with length 0x4480fcd013b5 considered as invalid data. Last known good position 0x1e5, 1 unknown elements in a row
fd:: error while seeking
[matroska,webm @ 0x7faf20000c80] 0x00 at pos 101285 (0x18ba5) invalid as first byte of an EBML number
[matroska,webm @ 0x7faf20000c80] Unknown element A3 at pos. 0x1daa8 with length 0x134 considered as invalid data. Last known good position 0x1e5, 20 unknown elements in a row
[matroska,webm @ 0x7faf20000c80] Unknown element 82 at pos. 0x1daab with length 0x4480fcd1f714 considered as invalid data. Last known good position 0x1e5, 1 unknown elements in a row
fd:: error while seeking
```

How to do in a working way?

**Edit from comments:**
OP states: The use of pipes is not mandatory, piping is my attempted solution. What I need is to use ffmpeg's `-bsf` options, and to display the result in ffplay, while being able to seek it.

Comment: Try to use it like this: `-bsf:v`. The [manual](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#Bitstream-Filters) says this: "The ff* tools have a -bsf option applied per stream, taking a comma-separated list of filters, whose parameters follow the filter name after a ’=’."

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, but that didn't help, even without `-bsf` options this command (`ffmpeg -i input.webm -c copy -f webm - | ffplay -`) is broken for whatever reason

Comment: How does it break? Adding a `-loglevel warning` parameter can help diagnose problems.

Comment: @harrymc add `-loglevel` option to `ffmpeg` or `ffplay`?

Comment: `ffplay` is a simpler command so start with it. If anything interesting comes up, please add it to your post.

Comment: My comment was deleted for whatever reason, but I'll state it again: Piping from `ffmpeg` to `ffplay` cannot give you a seekable playback experience. // In the first place, this appears to be x-y-ish. Why bother with bitstream filters if they'll be decompressed for playback anyway?

Comment: You need to do the `ffmpeg` to a file in order to play it. But why do you use `ffmpeg` at all to copy the video and play it at the same time. Why not use just `ffplay`?

Comment: @harrymc ffplay has no `-bsf` option

Comment: `-bsf` relates to filters specified on the `ffmpeg` command, but I don't see this in your command.

Comment: @harrymc huh? it is right in the command (in the question)

Comment: @1NN First of all, the `-bsf` is irrelevant to the command not working, it breaks with that option removed or not, second `-f matroska` didn't help same issues apply

Comment: You cannot pipe a file and expect to seek backwards and forwards through it. That is simply not how pipes work. They are one way streams of data and once data is read from the pipe it is removed from the pipe and effectively lost forever. Pipes may act like files in some ways but they are not. As mentioned by other comments piping directly from ffmpeg to ffplay is not going to be seekable and you will have to use a temporary file. Or tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve that requires these two commands bashed together.

Comment: @Mokubai this question is not about piping `ffmpeg` and `ffplay`, it is about effectively using the `-bsf` option on `ffplay`, piping is my attempted solution, this is an inverse XY problem where people think my question is about my attempted solution when it isn't

Comment: Then you need to actually give information, and at a minimum what your general requirements are. What operating system are you using? What restrictions do you have? For example *"I can't use temporary files"* or what filters you actually need? If we knew *why* `bsf` was important then an alternative might be suggested. "How to do this is a not broken way?" without any additional context gives the answer of "the way you want to do it is inherently broken, you can not do it" and we have no clue what paths are available to you because your question is so vague.

Comment: If `ffplay` supported `-bsf`, what *exactly* would you do with it to achieve what result?

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle that page appears to be inaccurate, I get this error `Failed to set value 'name=param' for option 'bsf:v': Option not found`

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle the command you provided earlier uses `-bsf` on `ffplay` directly is what you don't appear to understand

Comment: @FFmpegEnthusiast Please describe what you are hoping to accomplish, preferably using a concrete example. "Using `-bsf` with `ffplay`" isn't it. Maybe something like "achieving what `-bsf abc=xyz` does on `ffmpeg` but with `ffplay`"?

Comment: I checked the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1806019/revisions). Many of your edits were trivial. If this is your way to bump the question then [please stop](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5489/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I am doing this because of my frequent changes to my FFmpeg configuration and version. because it is now automatically updated I removed the version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bash script does the trick:

```
ffmpeg -v warning -i "$1" -bsf:v "$2=$3=$4" -c copy "temp.${1##*.}"
ffplay "temp.${1##*.}" 
rm "temp.${1##*.}"
```

Thanks to @1NN for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned in some comments, since you want to seek while using ffplay, you cannot use pipes, but you'll have to let ffmpeg.exe write a temporary file which is then passed to ffplay.

The script needs to do the three following steps:

1. run ffmpeg with the desired parameters and write the result into a temp file
2. run ffplay on the temp file
3. delete the temp file.

You can use any kind of scripting language. You have not stated your OS, but I'm on Windows so the easiest is to write a batch file, as follows.

- create a file called `bsfplay.bat` in your favorite text editor
- copy-paste the following code and save the file

  ```
    ffmpeg.exe -i input.webm -bsf:v %1^=%2^=%3 -c copy temp.webm
    ffplay.exe temp.webm 
    del temp.webm
  ```
- Note that `%1`,`%2`,`%3`  are variables in the batch file which will take command line arguments, and the `^` sign is needed to escape the `=`.
- now, from command prompt, you can do something like `bsfplay remove_extra freq k` which will call the `-bsf` filter `-bsf:v remove_extra=freq=k`
- or, if your video is h.264, you could do `bsfplay h264_metadata crop_left 16` which will call the bsf filter to crop 16 pixels on the left side of the video and save that into the temporary file. Then ffplay will read that file. Once you quit ffplay, the temporary file will be deleted.

Comment: My question stated my OS as of an edit 22 hours before your post

Answer (score -3):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to using the -bsf (bitstream filter) option with ffplay. It's possible that the combination of options you're using is causing issues with the input webm file. To effectively use -bsf with ffplay, you can try the following:

ffmpeg -i input.webm -c:v copy -bsf:v name=param -c:a copy -f webm - | ffplay -

Comment: Any piping from `ffmpeg` to `ffplay -` will break on seeking.